# Is there a way to parse the instagram ?__a=1 page programmatically?

Tags: python, json, instagram

```
https://www.instagram.com/example/?__a=1
```

When we add `?__a=1` to the end of the instagram account link, we get a page of json that contains many information of the user like:

```
{"logging_page_id":"profilePage_11288110","show_suggested_profiles":false,"graphql":{"user":{"biography":"\ud83d\udc47 \u2018Bangers & Ballads OUT NOW\u2019\ud83d\udc47","blocked_by_viewer":false,"country_block":false,"external_url":"https://bangers.lnk.to/bangersballadsIn","external_url_linkshimmed":"https://l.instagram.com/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fbangers.lnk.to%2FbangersballadsIn&e=ATMgu1_Mj-1mm4EEU1h6pkhKhcRYlXypnC3RezuzzA9l8ftEs832t_Gc3vk3VCI5GXPNRR84EcLgjog2","edge_followed_by":{"count":494093},"followed_by_viewer":false,"edge_follow":{"count":1536},"follows_viewer":false,"full_name":"example","has_channel":false,"has_blocked_viewer":false,"highlight_reel_count":14,"has_requested_viewer":false,"id":"11288110","is_business_account":true,"is_joined_recently":false,"business_category_name":"Creators & Celebrities","business_email":"gleaveeliot@gmail.com","business_phone_number":"","business_address_json":"{\"street_address\": \"\", \"zip_code\": \"\", \"city_name\": \"\", \"region_name\": \"\", \"countcode\": \"\"}","is_private":false,"is_verified":true,"edge_mutual_followed_by":{"count":0,"edges":...
```

I was wondering if I can just parse the `"id":"11288110"` by using a program.

I simply tried to use

```
for username in fashion_influencers:
        response = requests.get("https://www.instagram.com/example/?__a=1")
        print(response.text)
```

and see if I can access the data, but when I printed that out using request, nothing really showed up.

It doesn't have to be wise way, but I just need to prase the id of the instagram user given its username.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be logged in to see the response you are getting for `https://www.instagram.com/example/?__a=1`

Simply request `https://www.instagram.com/example` and search for the id in the response text

```
import requests

url = "https://www.instagram.com/example"

r  = requests.get(url)

data = r.text
query_str = 'logging_page_id":"profilePage_'
start = data.find(query_str)  + len(query_str)
print(data[start:start + 8])
```

Comment: Do I have to login manually to do this? Cant I do it with program?

Comment: @Dukakus17 Cannot do manually, you will have to use tools like Selenium, which automate web browsing https://www.seleniumhq.org

Comment: If this is for automation [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) is good. Pretty simple too.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<div class="instagram-feed" id="insta-feed"></div>

$(document).ready(function() {
  var list ='';     
  $.ajax({
    url:"https://www.instagram.com/<instagram id>/?__a=1",
    success: function (response) {
       var result =response.graphql.user.edge_owner_to_timeline_media.edges; 
       $.each(result, function(key, val) {
        list += ''+
        '<a target="_blank" href="https://www.instagram.com/p/'+val.node.shortcode+'"><img src="'+val.node.thumbnail_src+'" width=250></a>'+
        '';
         });
        $('#insta-feed').append(list);                      
    }
  });
});
```